# How to throw an exception in one android studio module and catch it in another module?

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I'm trying to split my application into two modules in android studio, a java library and a normal phone & tablet module, with the phone module depending on the java library. I added the json library to my java library module this way:

```
dependecies {
    compile 'org.json:json:20160212'
}
```

And then I added the dependency on the library module to the phone module this way:

```
dependencies {
    provided project(':libraryModule')
}
```

Now I have method in the java library throwing a JSONException:

```
public JSONObject fun() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("some","value");
    return obj;
}
```

I'm calling that method in a try-catch-block in my phone module:

```
public JSONObject boo() {
    MyObject my = new MyObject();
    try {
        return my.fun();
    } catch (JSONException e) {     //Exception works here
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Android Studio shows me on MouseOver within boo() that the fun() method throws an exception but it also tells me

> Exception 'org.json.JSONException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block'

but catching the parent class of JSONException, namely RuntimeException works. Furthermore Android Studio shows me no hint or error when I delete the try catch block entirely, which it did when I hadn't yet distributed the code into two modules via 'Unhandled Exception' hint.

*Note:
I intend to use the java library in a different non-android project.*

**Question:**
Is this an Android Studio issue and I shouldn't worry about it or do I have an entirely different problem, or am I just missing something here?

Comment: Need to see your code where you're throwing it and also where you're catching it

Comment: I expect the JSONException to be thrown by the put method of JSONObject, but it Android Studio doesn't complain anymore if I delete the try catch blocks or the throws clauses of the methods which should throw a JSONException.

Comment: `my.fun()` doesn't throw a `JSONException`, that is what that is saying.

Comment: but according to the documentation it does (it also shows that it does via mouseOver)

Comment: I stand corrected. Technically, it throws a [NullPointerException](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.json/json/20141113/org/json/JSONObject.java#JSONObject.put%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%29)

Comment: I think my confusion comes from the fact that the exception had to be caught when the fun() method wasn't in a separate module (I still have some code like that and when I delete the try catch block Android Studio complains about an unhandled exception.